# Django app to run a python ML application

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a python/pandas application that does data analysis and outputs reports to csv format. I would like to out an interactive front end UI on top of this application so the user can mix and match data, select parameters for scenario testing, have interactive charts and dashboards displayed on screen instead of csv etc.

I am looking to use Django, but for interactive charts, do I need to learn a javascript library (which one), or will Django be sufficient?

Comment: Django is a backend. So all things that should change dynamically should be handled through JavaScript. There are some Django libraries that can make that easier, but the workhorse at the frontend is JS.

Comment: So the JavaScript will call Django function which will then call a pandas function? Is that the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going to agree with Django (and moving your csv into a database).  Out of the box Django 2 brings sqlite which is a file based database that would offer you the ability to swap database files if you wanted.  I've found this (https://www.fusioncharts.com/django-charts/) django-charts package that incorporates interactive charts with Django, and seems to have lots of examples.

Comment: please do not answer off topic questions